# Ideas on how to optimize Ionic 3 App on Older Devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-proguard

I'm looking for ideas on how to optimize an ionic 3 app on older devices. We are using devices with the Specs below.

CPU 1.7 GHz dual core processor
Operating System Android 5.1 (Lollipop) with Mobility Extensions (Mx)
for a true enterprise-class OS
Memory 1 GB RAM / 8 GB Flash pSLC

The App we developed runs great in browser (obviously a lot more horsepower). The service calls are all optimized and quick but when we use the devices it seems like buttons clicks, screen transitions, etc are all slow and laggy. In general it seems like the app is very unresponsive/slow.

One thing we have done is install Crosswalk but the laggy/slowness still exists.

Any ideas on other things to do/try to help performance of an ionic 3 app on an older device?

Answer (score 0):

There is many thing You can do

1. run application `-prod` flag
2. optimize your css
3. enable Angular `enableProdMode()`
4. install [progurd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-proguard) `npm i cordova-plugin-proguard`
5. Enable Lazy Loading

> Read this good Article also
>
> https://www.protectator.ch/post/optimizing-performance-of-an-ionic-3-application